# Program to read PDFs

Tags: javascript, python, node.js

The program that I'm doing needs to get the text that is written on a PDF and then put the information on a spreadsheet, I also need to be able to just put the PDF on a folder and the run the code instead of putting the name of the PDF on the code.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -2):

This method will use an external module called PyPDF2 to convert PDF to text. This PyPDF2 package can allow you to convert, split, merge, and crop PDFs.

```
import PyPDF2
pdfFileObj = open('example.pdf', 'rb')
pdfReader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdfFileObj)
print(pdfReader.numPages)
pageObj = pdfReader.getPage(0)
print(pageObj.extractText())
pdfFileObj.close()
```